# php array in_array oddity

Tags: php, arrays

of all the languages i know im the weakest in php...

I have a script... that takes a csv file and does some stuff with it... fairly simple.

the issue i am having:
in_array('username', $headers) ... returns null... 
while... 
print_r ($headers); shows username being the first entry in the csv.

thoughts? mistakes i may have made?

TIA

code here

```
/// Turn the string into an array
            $rows = explode("\n", $this->raw_data);

            /// First row includes headers
            $headers = $rows[0];
            $headers = explode($this->delimiter, $headers);

            /// Trim spaces from $headers
            $headers = array_map('trim', $headers);

            /// Check that there are no empty headers. This can happen if there are delimiters at the end of the file
            foreach($headers as $header){

                    if(!empty($header)){
                            $headers2[] = $header;
                    }
            }
            $headers = $headers2;

            if(! in_array('password', $headers)){
                    /// Add password column for generated passwords
                    $headers[] = 'password';
            }
            /// Add status column to the headers
            $headers[] = 'status';

            $this->headers = $headers;

            /// Check that at least username, name and email are provided in the headers
            if(!in_array('username', $headers) ||
               !in_array('name', $headers) ||
               !in_array('email', $headers)){

               echo "error\n";   
               return false;
            }
```

Comment: its returning false. id like it to return true :)

Comment: I'd like to run a test but I've got no idea what your data looks like, can we get a sample, even if it's username0,email0,blah0\nuername1,email1....

Comment: http://kirbs.me/partial_UserData_v13.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built in `str_getcsv()` function. Try replacing the `$headers` variable assignment with

```
$headers = str_getcsv($rows[0], $this->delimiter);
```

Then find the value(column) you want and loop through the rest of the `$rows` using the same `str_getcsv()` function to get the matches you need.

You may want to use the `file()` function to grab the file in an array delimited by newlines to begin with, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check the first three functions [in this list](https://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=csv&lang=en) . Your problem can arise from several causes. Start by elimination of unnecessary parsing by using the built in CSV function.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see code that sets $headers2 to be an array. Is the first assignment to that variable getting lost once the second assignment happens which turns it into an array?

Comment: i do the print_r ($headers); directly before the if statement that checks username...  the output is such...
    Array ( [0] => ﻿username [1] => password [2] => email [3] => name )